# Single title in JLine 3 help output

Tags: jline, jline3

How do I customize the help command in JLine 3? The help in my [JLine 3 shell sample](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/manager-picocli) displays as:

```
manager> help
  System:
    exit   exit from app/script
    help   command help
  Builtins:
  ShellCommandRegistry:
    create Create some stuff with minimal fuss...
    delete Deletes some stuff with minimal fuss...
    list   List some stuff with minimal fuss...
```

I'd like to replace the section titles ("System:", "Builtins:", and "ShellCommandRegistry:") with single "Commands:" title like:

```
manager> help
  Commands:
    exit   exit from app/script
    help   command help
    create Create some stuff with minimal fuss...
    delete Deletes some stuff with minimal fuss...
    list   List some stuff with minimal fuss...
```

Any ideas how to control this in JLine 3?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to customize command groupings.

Will be fixed in next JLine version (> 3.15.0):
Added help command options: --nogroups (--groups) and --info.
Default grouping behaviour can be controlled by setting

```
systemRegistry.setGroupCommandsInHelp(true/false)
```

.

```
groovy-repl> help --help
help -  command help
Usage: help [TOPIC...]
  -? --help                      Displays command help
     --nogroups                  Commands are not grouped by registeries
  -i --info                      List commands with a short command infos
groovy-repl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jline 3.20.0:

I wrote my own Registry and registered the other into this one, like this:

```java
MyAppCommands myAppCommands = new MyAppCommands(parser, terminal, workDir, null);
myAppCommands.setCommandRegistries(builtins, picocliCommands);
myAppCommands.register("help", myAppCommands);
```

where MyAppCommands extends SystemRegistryImpl. Then the help command shows only the class-name "MyAppCommands:"

Therefore if you name your registry class "Commands" you'll get your desired result!